# Showing two sets are equal special case of the empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume I want to show that $A=B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets. The standard way to do this elementary is that one takes $x\in A$ and shows that $x\in B$. Then one takes $x\in B$ and shows that $x\in A$. My concern is the following:

I implicitly assume that I can take such an element and therefore, assume that that $A$ is non-empty. If it was, does this proof still hold as I have 'hidden' forall quantors?
Or do I have to distinguish cases?

Comment: I think it still holds. The implication (in one direction) is "if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$". If the hypothesis is not satisfied, the implication is still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not really "implicitly assuming that YOU can take an element".

What you need to prove is

> If someone gives me an $x$ and it turns out that his $x$ is an element of $A$, then I can prove it is an element of $B$ too.

(and conversely with $A$ and $B$ swapped).

It's not your job to make sure that your adversary *can* find an $x$ that is in $A$. All you need to do is be prepared in case he *does*. (Which would mean that you find yourself in a situation where $A$ happens to be non-empty, and you can use that knowledge freely while arguing that $x\in B$).

If you *know* that $A$ is empty, then you can make the promise willy-nilly -- since in that case you *know* that the adversary will never be able give you an $x\in A$, you can calmly promise to do *anything* if he does, because you will never actually have to make good on that promise.